# How to use Google Analytics in a ReactRouter V4 Switch setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-analytics, react-router

I am trying to implement Google Analytics in my React single page application but to do that I understand that I need to use the `history` prop. I am using a Switch setup, and this will not seem to work.

```
<Switch history={history}>
    <Route exact path="/" component={place}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={otherplace}/>
    <Route component={error}/>
</Switch>
```

If I change the `<Switch>` to a `<Router>` the analytics work but the error page renders on every page and when the URL path changes the page requires a refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the error component is on all routes.

Try this:
Add a distinct 404 error route:

```
<Route path='/404' component={error} />
```

Route all unmatched routes to it:

```
<Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
```

This should show the error component only on pages that don't exist.

Here's a switch that does that:

```
<Switch history={history}>
    <Route exact path="/" component={place}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={otherplace}/>
    <Route path='/404' component={error} />
    <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question, the history tag doesn't work with <Switch>